# Join and aggregate result and insert blanks for missing appendants

Tags: postgresql, join, aggregate, csv

Consider these two simplified tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "sources"
(
    "id" serial NOT NULL,
    "name" text NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "sources_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);

CREATE TABLE "values"
(
    "time" timestamp NOT NULL,
    "source_id" integer NOT NULL,
    "value" json,
    CONSTRAINT "values_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("time", "source_id"),
    CONSTRAINT "values_sources_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("source_id")
        REFERENCES "sources" ("id")
);
```

The intention is that one table keeps sources represented by name and the other table keeps timestamped values with a reference to the corresponding source. I took json just as an arbitrary example.

Sample data:

```sql
INSERT INTO "sources" ("id", "name") VALUES
    (1, 'Source 1'),
    (2, 'Source 2'),
    (3, 'Source 3')
;
```

```sql
INSERT INTO "values" ("time", "source_id", "value") VALUES
    ('2014-01-01 12:00:00', 1, '123'),
    ('2014-01-01 12:00:00', 2, 'true'),
    ('2014-01-01 12:00:00', 3, '1.23'),

    ('2014-01-01 13:00:00', 1, '456'),
    -- hint: no data for source 2
    ('2014-01-01 13:00:00', 3, '4.56'),

    ('2014-01-01 14:00:00', 1, '789'),
    ('2014-01-01 14:00:00', 2, 'false')
    -- hint: no data for source 3
;
```

I now want a query returning all the values and their sources grouped by timestamp.

The best (and probably most simple) I could come up with is this:

```sql
SELECT "time", array_agg("name"), array_agg("value") FROM "sources", "values"
WHERE "sources"."id" = "values"."source_id"
GROUP BY "time" ORDER BY "time";
```

```
"2014-01-01 12:00:00";"{"Source 1","Source 2","Source 3"}";"{123,true,1.23}"
"2014-01-01 13:00:00";"{"Source 1","Source 3"}";"{456,4.56}"
"2014-01-01 14:00:00";"{"Source 1","Source 2"}";"{789,false}"
```

This works good for me, however it would be a lot better if it would contain blank values for *missing* sources within a group of timestamp. The desired result would look like this:

```
"2014-01-01 12:00:00";"{"Source 1","Source 2","Source 3"}";"{123,true,1.23}"
"2014-01-01 13:00:00";"{"Source 1",,"Source 3"}";"{456,,4.56}"
"2014-01-01 14:00:00";"{"Source 1","Source 2",}";"{789,false,}"
```

If there was a fourth source for example, with no values at all, I want it to appear in the result as well. What I basicly want here is a complete list of all sources and their values grouped by timestamp with blanks for sources and their values in case there is no record for that specific group.

**What's the best way to accomplish this task?** And also, is this even a *good* approach of doing it like this? I mean, it would be even better if I could get a column for each source and value pair. Or probably not? My goal is to make it as much **CSV-friendly** as I can get it. As it is now, I do quite a lot in the next layer of business logic to get it into that, but it feels like I am not using my DBMS as I should with all its potentials.

As a side note, this is what my CSV file looks like:

```
timestamp;Source 1;Source 2;Source 3    
"2014-01-01 12:00:00";123;true;1.23
"2014-01-01 13:00:00";456;;4.56
"2014-01-01 14:00:00";789;false;
```

Comment: Have you tried a `LEFT JOIN` between the 2 tables?

Comment: And really, a table named `values`? I mean it's not a reserved keyword in Postgres but I'd strongly suggest you pick another name.

Comment: Yes, but isn't that basicly the same as I do now, just with another syntax? And yes, `values`. It's just an example I came up with.

Comment: I meant to use LEFT join to get also the blank values for missing sources. You are currently doing an (implicit) INNER join.

Comment: Yes, I did that. But it still swallows the blank values. I am not sure why. I suspect `array_agg()` swallows them. Either way, no matter how I join them, they get lost in the process.

Comment: Yes, my bad. It's not the array_agg, it's that you want a left join, starting from all distinct sources and all disticnt timestamps. See this: [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/105bd/9)

Comment: Thanks, that gets me the desired output and I understand the concept behind it. Now I just need to _play around with it_ so it doesn't take ~25 times longer than the simple join I am doing now ...

Comment: Well, CROSS joins are not usually very efficient. It might help if you have an index on `(time)` or even better, if that `(SELECT DISTINCT time ...)` is a separate base table.